# Need to draw a diagram dynamically using php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a requirement,drawing a open plot diagram using input dimensions of 4 sides.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CRqfXdOSJb7gz7sPzc-w0Ag&q=real+estate+floor+plan+open+plot+images&oq=real+estate+floor+plan+open+plot+images&gs_l=img.3...40791.43818..44131...0.0..0.175.1327.0j10......0....1..gws-wiz-img.ONTZ6f8LBaE&ved=0ahUKEwiTu7SYz5HlAhU-8HMBHc0nDIoQ4dUDCAY&uact=5#imgdii=IfI5Qr1IfzbbzM:&imgrc=O-RkY4-5OUfoeM:

I want plot diagram with dimensions and angles,i will give input as individual plot dimensions.

Comment: _i want_ is not a question, please read [ask]

Comment: i have following inputs:
    Line 1
    Length = 77.23 feet 
    Angle = N3 18' 25" E

    Line 2
    Length = 65.81 feet 
    Angle = N86 41' 1" E

    Line 3
    Length = 58.97 feet 
    Angle = S7 5' 56" E

    Line 4
    Length = 57.7 feet 
    Angle = S67 9' 50" W

    Arc 1
    Arc Length = 25.16 feet
    Radius = 27.13 feet
output like:https://d2haqc5836ials.cloudfront.net/live/KB-00850/850-fig1-11.jpg?1557786080

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use GD library to draw stuff in PHP.

Please go through:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: i want output like:https://d2haqc5836ials.cloudfront.net/live/KB-00850/850-fig1-11.jpg?1557786080